# How do I "interpret" escaped characters in a string?

Tags: string, rust, escaping

I want to process a string containing a backslash followed by an escapable character as if they were one character.

```
let raw = r#"\""#;
let cooked = raw.process_escape_character_magic();
```

Right now, `raw` has 2 characters: `\` and `"`. But what I actually want is `cooked`, which only has one character: `"`.

How do I get `cooked`?

I was thinking about using regex, but I feel like there should probably be a better way.

Comment: Should every backslash + some character in the string be replaced with that character, or do different escape sequences mean different things? (Or, if you’d like to answer something that addresses a lot of potential questions at once: where did you get the string/which format is it in?)

Comment: @Ry- Same meaning as in Rust's own strings, i.e. `"\n"` gives a newline character, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like using iterators in Rust, and I think that's a perfect usecase:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
enum MyError {
    EscapeAtEndOfString,
    InvalidEscapedChar(char),
}

struct InterpretEscapedString<'a> {
    s: std::str::Chars<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for InterpretEscapedString<'a> {
    type Item = Result<char, MyError>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.s.next().map(|c| match c {
            '\\' => match self.s.next() {
                None => Err(MyError::EscapeAtEndOfString),
                Some('n') => Ok('\n'),
                Some('\\') => Ok('\\'),
                // etc.
                Some(c) => Err(MyError::InvalidEscapedChar(c)),
            },
            c => Ok(c),
        })
    }
}

fn interpret_escaped_string(s: &str) -> Result<String, MyError> {
    (InterpretEscapedString { s: s.chars() }).collect()
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(interpret_escaped_string(r#""#), Ok("".into()));
    assert_eq!(interpret_escaped_string(r#"a"#), Ok("a".into()));
    assert_eq!(interpret_escaped_string(r#"\"#), Err(MyError::EscapeAtEndOfString));
    assert_eq!(interpret_escaped_string(r#"\\"#), Ok("\\".into()));
    assert_eq!(interpret_escaped_string(r#"a\n"#), Ok("a\n".into()));
    assert_eq!(interpret_escaped_string(r#"a\."#), Err(MyError::InvalidEscapedChar('.')));
}
```

More complete implementation of such a module [in the playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=434f9de2a5d921e104cae9bd2d8bcdb8).

Comment: No way to get all escaped characters? i.e. `\"`, `\\`, `\t`, `\n`, etc.? Or do we have to manually put them in the match statement? Close enough either way I suppose, but still leaves a bad taste in my mouth.

Comment: @kkeey There's no reason that would be in the std lib. That's an information internal to the compiler.