# How do I handle ansi escape sequences from a file?

Tags: rust, escaping, ansi-escape

I'm writing my own shell from scratch (`shark` - shell of ark). Ark is just my initials.

Most of things are really good working, e.c. arrows / history / command execution, input buffer timeout with VTIME and VMIN to handle ascii esc sequences.

Most of the time I use a simple prompt hardcoded, just to have one, but with color:

```
&tty.stdout.write(b"\x1b[1;32m[ shark ]\x1b[0m $");
```

And this works well, but I want to get my environment from the rc file, `.sharkrc`.

In this file I've the simple code:

```bash
PS1='\x1b[1;32m[ shark ]\x1b[0m $ '
```

At the start of the shell the rc file gets read and parsed and then the prompt looks like:

```
\x1b[1;32m[ shark ]\x1b[0m $
```

No colors, and I know what the problem is actually: it is a pure string and will printed as a string, even it is: `prompt.as_bytes()`,

There is no `\x1b[..` sequence, just the chars `\` then `x` then `1` then `b` and so on.

But here is the problem, I want to do this from scratch so I need a little help, to handle the ansi esc codes when the strings come from a file.

My last idea was to use regex and seek all the ansi codes out of a string and then write it separate.

But is there a simpler method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I "interpret" escaped characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58551211/how-do-i-interpret-escaped-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: not really, but thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself, the code is still bit messie, but it was from try and error. Now it works and i know how tho handle ANSI EscCodes.

Here the code:

```
pub fn parse_from_str( text: &str, tty: &Terminal ) {

    let mut ansi_code    = false;
    let mut ansi_blk     : Vec<char> = Vec::new();  
    let mut non_ansi_blk : Vec<char> = Vec::new();

    let ansi_scan : [char; 4 ] = [ '\\', 'x', 'b', 'm' ];

    for (index, byte) in text.chars().enumerate() {

        if byte == '\\' {
            ansi_code = true;
            //println!("\rfound \\");
            if !non_ansi_blk.is_empty() {
                write!(&tty.stdout, "{}", non_ansi_blk.iter().collect::<String>());
                non_ansi_blk.clear();
            }

        } else if ansi_code == true && !ansi_scan.contains(&byte)  {

            if text.as_bytes()[index - 1] == b'x' { continue; }

            //println!("\rPush ANSI: {}", byte);
            ansi_blk.push(byte);
        
        } else if ansi_code == true && byte == 'm' {
            ansi_code = false;
        
            write!(&tty.stdout, "\x1b{}m", ansi_blk.iter().collect::<String>());
            ansi_blk.clear();

        } else if ansi_code == false  {
            //println!("\rPush non ANSI: {}", byte);
            non_ansi_blk.push(byte);
        }
    }

    if !non_ansi_blk.is_empty() {
        write!(&tty.stdout, "{}", non_ansi_blk.iter().collect::<String>());
        non_ansi_blk.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can drop all the code except for the bit scanning for `['\\', 'x', 'b', 'm']`, as you just replace the rest of the bytes with themselves.

Comment: This also parses `r"\[1;32m"` and various other invalid sequences as valid ascii escape sequences. (i.e. this string as input produces `"\u{1b}[1;32m"` when it should probably produce `r"\[1;32m"` or maybe `"[1;32m"`)

Comment: sorry, but i don't get it. i tried the whole night, write and rewrite the code and got zero success. with r"\... or r#... nothing works as i need it. still prints the ansi code as a sting and not the ansi 'm' color function.

Comment: it's really strange, cause my code above works good "per se": the string in .sharkrc: `PROMPT=\x1b[38;2;32;252;103m[ \x1b[38;2;248;10;213mUSERNAME\x1b[38;2;252;168;65m@\x1b[38;2;248;10;213mHOSTNAME \x1b[38;2;32;252;103m]\x1b[0m $` and the prompt in my shell is exact as it should be "funny colored" :)

Comment: What I mean is that when you put `\x[38;2;32;252;103m[whatever]\x[0m` in your `.sharkrc` it'll still print `[whatever]` in colour, but it shouldn't because the original string does not contain any ascii escape codes whatsoever. Similarly with `\xbbbbbbm[32;0mwhatever`

Comment: Ahhh now it has "klick gemacht", thanky you,i think it is simpler to do the parsing with regex.

Comment: I think you'll be better off just interpreting `\x1b` as a `\u{1b}` like in the Q/A I linked under your question. Or using one of the [ANSI escape parsing crates](https://crates.io/search?q=ansi%20escape%20parser)

Comment: Here is [the code from the linked Q/A with a branch that interprets `\x..` escape sequences](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5019da0d82dd48ce278b507a9a97029c)